# Kotlin Jetpack Compose - MutableStateFlow detect nested changes

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel

I have a variable of type `MutableStateFlow<List<Equipment>?>` and I'd like to update the UI when the property of an `Equipment` object inside the list changes.

I have tried to

1. Make a copy of the list and assign it with value
2. Make a copy of the element I'm changing in the list
3. Use the update method

None of them works and the UI is not updated.

Comment: i think you forgot to call 'viewModel.yourState.collectAsState.value' in your composable

Answer (score 0):

if a property of a object changes it is considers as structural change not referential change and compose wont react to structural changes u can do the following [incase of data class use .copy() method ]

```
//Create a mutable state List 


val list = mutableStateListOf<String>("A","B","C")
                    
//update like this

list[2]=list[2]+"Hello"
```

3rd object in the list will get replaced and notified to respected composables

for non primitive

```
 //Create a mutable state List 
                    
  data class Some(val x:String = "A")
                    
  val list = mutableStateListOf<Some>(Some("A"),Some("B"),Some("C"))
                    
//update like this

list[2]=list[2].copy(x = "New value")
```